# Break at spaces and select string contianing numbers

Tags: python, regex

In python, I want a to convert this with regex

`"Something 19.28 else" -> "19.28"`

`"Someone 18.16-one-0 other" -> "18.16-one-0"`

It means, break at whitespaces and select the one containing numbers.

**SOLUTION:**
After some research I figured it out myself.

```
string = "Someone 18.16-one-0 other"
string = re.search('(?<=\s)\d.*?(?=\s|\Z)', string).group()

__________________________________________

output => 18.16-one-0
```

the function from python module **re** searches for the match in the argument passed after the pattern and return **match object**, then the `.group()` convert the **match object** to a string.

The regex `(?<=\s)\d.*?(?=\s|\Z)` can be broken into three parts

1. `(?<=\s)` => this matches all string which contain space before them.
2. `\d.*` => this matches the string exactly after the space.
3. `?(?=\s|\Z)` => this matches only if the previous match contains a space (denoted by `/s`) or (denoted by `|`) EOL (end of line denoted as `/Z`).

**Note**: An extra `?` is used before `(` here. It is used to create a non-greedy lookahead, which ends at the first occurence, otherwise, it will continue matching all.

so, this searches for digits preceded by a space and followed by a space or end of line.

Thanks to the community for help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to fit your question:

```
foo = 'foo 19.29 bar'
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

terms = foo.split()
converted = None

for i in terms:
    for j in numbers:
        if j in i:
            converted = i
            break

print(converted)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know this can be easily done with loop, But I need regex for this.

Comment: @decipher doing a task like this using regex would be unnecessarily complex. Just stick to doing it with a loop in my opinion.

Comment: But regex is fast for this case, like we have to do for 20-30 values it will be slow

Comment: _"I need regex"_ - then show the code how that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply split the string and search for numbers in the string

```
import re
text = "Someone 18.16-one-0 other"

print(''.join([i for i in text.split() if re.search(r'\d', i)]))

>>> 18.16-one-0
```